# this.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy haciendo una web en react, donde tengo un login y registro, ambos usan un efecto tipo google. Originalmente el código es html puro, pero yo quiero hacerlo con react. Lo que hace el set attribute es importante para que funcione, ya intente todo pero nada.

```
...
<input id="pass-input" type="password" name="password" required onKeyUp={this.setAttribute('value', this.value)} className="IEwqw inpt_ctrl focus:bg-white focus:border-gray password" autoComplete="ignoreThis" value="" />
<label>Password</label>
...
```

Pero en la consola me da el error:
"this.setAttribute is not a function"

Comment: Me parece que te faltan las comillas. De todos modos deberías evitar escribir funciones in line que producen código propenso a errores y hacen depender siempre el HTML de JavaScript dificultando el mantenimiento. Es mejor escuchar los eventos por el id del elemento, por su clase o por otro selector según el caso, trasladando todo lo que sea JavaScript a JavaScript y liberando el HTML.

Comment: Segun entiendo en react cuando haces referencia a this estas haciendo referencia es al componente en react y no al elemento, pues eso me dijeron, pero pues... no he usado react. (Hablo solo de este caso en especifico, del HTML)

Comment: no entiendo muy bien lo que intentas hacer, pero estas queriendo almacenar un dato??

Comment: puedo ayudarte, pero necesitaría mas información sobre lo que intentas hacer y una vista mas compleja de tu código, de lo contrario no se entiende tu problema

Comment: Tengo un formulario de login y registro ambos compareten el mismo efecto tipo google. En html normal me funcionaba sin problemas, pero como cambie a react empecé a tener un error. Lo que hace el OnkeyUp, es que cuando se pone una letra se debe poner al input(asi funciona la logica del css y html que hacen funcionar el efecto) con el this.setAttribute lo que hago es poner el texto que se escribio en ese mismo input.

Comment: No entiendo bien el porque estas haciendo eso, personalmente creo que no es el camino correcto, pero prueba con onKeyUp={(event)=>event.target.setAttribute('value', event.target.value)}, te digo que no me da sentido lo que estas haciendo ya que el evento onKeyUp se lanza cuando el usuario suelta la tecla, lo que quiere decir que ya esta cambiando el valor del input. No veo la necesidad que tu lo vuelvas a cambiar desde el evento.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el evento onchange

pasa el value al state aqui un ejemplo de input basico

```
    <input 
  type="text" 
  value={name} 
  onChange={(e) => {
    const { value } = e.target
   
    this.setState({ name: value })
  }} 
/>
```

necesitaria mas codigo de lo que estas haciendo para poder  tener un mejor contexto y saber si estas usando clases o hooks para poder ayudarte espero te sirva en la docuementacion de React obtendras mas informacion en este enlace https://es.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html